# How to use Degrafa AutoShapes

Tags: apache-flex, degrafa

I see a degrafa autoshape that I want to use but it seems like there are no autoshapes included in the swc.  What do I have to do to use an autoshape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autoshapes are more recent than the last official swc release (beta 3.1). You need to get the code from svn to build your own swc, or wait for a new official swc (this should be within the next week or so, as we are planning a new beta release). 
-Degrafa

Comment: awesome, looking forward to it!